# Binding to a Property of an static object in another class

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have tried for several hours to find a solution for my problem. I hope someone can help me here.

First my scenario:

My solution has 3 projects actually.

- The project with the Main Window (ProductionDataInput).
- A project that provides some LoginDialogs (LoginDialogs).
- A project with some classes that I need in the whole solution. `PDIServices`, for example, is the currently logged on user. For this, I have created a Class called `CardUser` in the `PDIServices` project, when a user logs in via the `LoginDialog`. A static object of type `CardUser` will be set to a new instance in the static `PDIObjects` class. The goal is to have access on that static `CardUser` object from the whole solution.

Some ideas for the procedure I have thought of:

- The application starts with the `MainWindow` and the user logs in via the `LoginDialog`, which is called from an event of the `MainWindow`.
- The `LoginDialog` calls the static method `CreateAndSetCardUser()` from the `CardUser` class. A new instance of `CardUser` will be created and set to the `PDIObjects.CardUser` property.

CardUser class:

```
public class CardUser : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static void CreateAndSetCardUser(string idcard, string name, string prename, string department)
    {
        PDIObjects.CardUser = new CardUser(idcard, name, prename, department);
    }

    public static void UnsetCardUser()
    {
        PDIObjects.CardUser = null;
    }
}

public static class PDIObjects
{
    private static CardUser cardUser;
    public static CardUser CardUser
    {
        get { return PDIObjects.cardUser; }
        set
        {
            PDIObjects.cardUser = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When no user is logged on the `CardUser` object, it is set to `null`. When a user is logged on, I want to show the name and maybe some other information on a component of the `MainWindow`.  It is at this point I am stuck.

I have tried to create a binding to the properties of the `CardUser` object, but with no success.

```
<telerik:Tile 
    Name="tiCardLogin" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    TileType="Single" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Height="100" 
    Width="100" 
    Background="#0078ac" 
    ToolTip="Login" 
    local:FrameworkElementExt.AttachIsPressed="True"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="tiCardLogin_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
    Style="{DynamicResource LoginTileStyle}"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static PDIServices:PDIObjects.CardUser}}"
    >
    <telerik:Label 
        Content="{Binding Name}" 
        Foreground="White" 
        FontSize="20" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        />
</telerik:Tile>
```

Any tips to achieve my goal? What would be the best practice? Why isn't the Binding working?

Comment: The Question you have posted has nothing to do with the question I have asked. I asked for help with the binding expression and if the design of my solution makes sense. The question of which you think mine is a duplicate of is about the this qualifier in a static context...

Comment: For some reason, you drop no hints about exactly how your code "doesn't work", but I'm guessing you're just not seeing anything in the label. Where are you raising `PropertyChanged` for `PDIObjects.CardUser`? Nowhere, that I can see. As far as the Binding knows, it never changes from null, because you never tell anybody it changed. Even if you did, it can be tricky to get `PropertyChanged` notifications to work with static properties. Clemens pointed you to an answer *which tells you how to do that*. That's what you need to do. I know you're the expert. But he's even experter.

Comment: One more thing (this is in the blog post linked from the answer you didn't feel like reading): Get rid of your `Tile.DataContext` binding and use this binding for your label content: `{Binding Path=(PDIServices:PDIObjects.CardUser).Name}` (the parens are not optional, and with the parens, Path is not optional), or else change `Source` to `Path` in the `DataContext` binding. But it's not recommended practice to bind `DataContext` explicitly like that.